# Adjust the row height to height of image

Tags: excel, vba, image

I want to adjust the row height to the inserted image.

I tried `cell.EntireRow = pic.Height`. It loops through several worksheets to find the code then selects the empty cell next to it so the image gets inserted there. Also not sure if this is the way to go through the entire worksheet as there is usually more that one Photo1 there. I can do the photo2 and photo3 using whatever solution is found.

```vb
Private Sub cmdInsertPhoto1_Click()
'insert the photo1 from the folder into each worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim strFile As String
Dim imgFile As String
Dim localFilename As String
Dim pic As Picture
Dim findit As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
'delete the two sheets if they still exist
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name = "PDFPrint" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("PDFPrint").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next
 
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name = "DataSheet" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("DataSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next
    
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Photos1\")
  
'Loop through all worksheets
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Select

    Set rng = Range("A:A")
    ws.Unprotect
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell = "CG Code" Then
            'find the next adjacent cell value of CG Code
            strFile = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'the cg code value
            imgFile = strFile & ".png" 'the png imgFile name
            localFilename = folder & "\" & imgFile 'the full location
               
            'just find Photo1 cell and select the adjacent cell to insert the image
            findit = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Photo1", MatchCase:=True).Offset(0, 1).Select
       
            Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(localFilename)
            With pic
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .ShapeRange.Width = 200
                .ShapeRange.Height = 200 'max row height is 409.5
                .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            End With
            cell.EntireRow = pic.Height
        End If
        
        'delete photo after insert
        'Kill localFilename
     Next cell
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' let user know its been completed
MsgBox ("Worksheets created")
End Sub
```

What it looks like
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the rowheight property of the range object: `cell.EntireRow.RowHeight= pic.Height`

As you wrote it (`cell.EntireRow = pic.Height`) you implicitly used the default property of `cell.EntireRow` which is `value`)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it. for anyone else its cell was selected so, this works for me:

```
'just find Photo1 cell and select the adjacent cell to insert the image
       findit = Range("A:A").Find(what:="Photo1", MatchCase:=True).Offset(0, 1).Select
       ActiveCell.EntireRow.RowHeight = 200 'max row height is 409.5
            
       Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(localFilename)
         With pic
            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .ShapeRange.Width = 200
            '.ShapeRange.Height = 200 'max row height is 409.5
            .ShapeRange.Height = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Height
            .ShapeRange.Top = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Top
            .ShapeRange.Left = ActiveCell.MergeArea.Left
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
         End With
```